# Trying to complete a vowel counting program in ASM, but there's always an "illegal instruction" error

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data        ;initialize ds register
    mov ds,AX
    mov si,offset String    ;initialize p
    mov cx,len      ;length in CX register
    mov bl,00       ;vowel count=0
BACK:   mov al,[si]
    cmp al,'a'
    jb VOWEL
    cmp al,'z'      ;Convert the character to upper case
    ja VOWEL
    sub al,20H
VOWEL:  cmp al,'A'
    jnz a3
    inc bl
    jmp a2
a3: cmp al,'E'
    jnz a4
    inc bl
    jmp a2
a4: cmp al,'I'
    jnz a5
    inc BL
    jmp a2
a5: cmp al,'O'
    jnz a6
    inc bl
    jmp a2
a6: cmp al,'U'
    jmp a2
    inc bl
a2: inc si
    loop BACK
    mov si, ax
    mov ax, 4C00H
    int 21h
main endp
.data
    string db "Kono taisetsu na omoi wa wasurenai","$"
    len dw string
    **VOWEL db?** <- considers this as an illegal instruction
end main
```

Comment: space needed vetween `db` abd the `?` maybe?

Comment: I tried that, but it will consider VOWEL a different symbol.

Comment: You also have a label called `VOWEL`  in your code and a  `VOWEL` label in your data. They have to have a different name.

Comment: Which one should I edit, the vowel in the code or the vowel label?

Comment: Doesn't matter one of them has to change. Doesn't matter which.

Comment: It didn't change anything. It still considers the "vowel db" as an illegal instruction.

Comment: For instance you can change the code to be `jb VOWEL_CHK` and the line `ja VOWEL_CHK` and the line `VOWEL:  cmp al,'A'`

Comment: Did you put a space between `db` and the `?` as I suggested. You need a space between them or the assembler will choke on it. The line should be `VOWEL db ?`, not `VOWEL db?`

Comment: It added two more errors of "Undefined symbol: VOWEL_CHK". I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Did you modify it to be `VOWEL_CHK` in the 3 spots I told you to?

Comment: Yes. The illegal instruction error is now gone.

Comment: Yes, I just did. There are no more errors, but when I tried to execute it, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's something else altogether. You'll have to learn to use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Uninitialized data goes into the BSS section in MASM denoted by `data?`. That is why you got the illegal instruction error.

```
        .data?

Vowel:  db  ?, ?, ?             ; Reserves 3 bytes
        dw  ?, ?                ; Reserves 4 bytes 2 word
 Buff:  db  100 dup<?>          ; Reserves 100 bytes
```

> This has nothing to do with what you asked, but you may find it helpful.

As string is pointed to by DS:SI you can use an X86 instruction conducive to that and at the same time, dispense with the counter in CX.

```
    L0: lodsb                   ; Reads byte from DS:SI and increments SI
        cmp     al, '?'         ; Test if at end of string
        jz      Finished        ; You need a label called

        and     al, 5FH         ; Convert letter to uppercase
        cmp     al,'A'
        jz      Bump
        cmp     al,'E'
        jz      Bump

        ......

        cmp     al,'U'
        jnz     L0

 Bump:  inc     bl
        jmp     L0

Finished:
```